# HTML encoding angle brackets in questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, markdown

This is a problem I'm seen primarily with new users.

Questions and answers are entered which sometimes use the < > angle bracket characters for emphasis, URLs (e.g. `http://<server>/site`), poorly formatted code or occasionally ASCII art. As a result what's been entered is not displayed and makes little or no sense. (Unfortunately this isn't noticed by them or most answerers.)

Is it possible that unless the angle brackets contain an allowed HTML tag that they are simply HTML encoded instead so they still display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Markdown already offers an easy way to escape such characters.  This proposal makes things much more difficult for a renderer that's already easily confused.  It's so easy for someone else to go in and clean it up that I just don't see the point.

Comment: The point is because someone answering the question doesn't appear to notice and writes the wrong answer because of this. Well I assume they don't notice or I'd see more edits for this besides mine.

Comment: It would be useful to edit and specify the "easy way" you are referring to. I use &lt; and &gt; and I just learned about selecting and clicking the 101010 button. Is there another way?

Comment: I can never get the markdown to work right. I always have to use &lt;. (even if I am inside of a <pre><code> block